# Scraping data over websockets

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, websocket, scrapy

I am trying to get the daily price data from this specific webpage:

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/CS1/amundi/company-page

Those data are represented in the chart.

I run out of idea to try to reach those data. I assume that those data are transfered though one of the websocket connection that is made and retrievable in the browser console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1ex2.png)

I tried to simulate the websocket connection and send the same binary than the front app.

```
from websocket import create_connection

s = create_connection("wss://82-99-29-151.infrontservices.com/wsrt/2/4")

hex_1 = "3e000000010..."
hex_2 = "13000000010..."
hex_3 = "1e000000010..."

ws.send(binascii.unhexlify(hex_1))
ws.send(binascii.unhexlify(hex_2))
ws.send(binascii.unhexlify(hex_3))

result =  ws.recv()
```

Then I tried to decode this response with all the possible encoding as follow:

```
import binascii
from encodings.aliases import aliases

for v in [v for k, v in aliases.items()]:
    try:
        print(result.decode(v))
    except:
        print(f"ERROR {v}")
```

And naturally, I have no interpretable output that I can exploit. I could think that a cipher is used here. But I have no more idea how to investigate further.

Do you have any idea about that? :)

Thanks in advance !

AL Ko

### EDIT 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAVXw.png)

We can see one the datapoint with the value 16990 for a given date. This is what I am looking for is the whole time series of the chart.

Comment: Hey AL Ko, welcome to Stackoverflow. I checked out the site you're trying to scrape from, and it seems the website is also transmitting this info to your browser via JSON (rest request):
https://api.londonstockexchange.com/api/gw/lse/instruments/alldata/CS1

if the data you're looking for is inside this JSON, you can make a get request to that URL relatively easy. Be aware that some sites dont like it - or prohibit - data scraping, and a malformed script can quickly look like a DOS attack for them, and block you. Read up upon it before using that data for personal or public use.

Comment: Did you inspect it through crome dev tool? Does it uses header or any other authentication or token?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers! 

I noticed those data but it is not the one I am looking for. I would like to have the full time series appearing on the chart. C.F. edit

Comment: Hey Prashant,
Yes, I am using the Chrome dev tool. Indeed, I could find a Sec-WebSocket-Key and a Sec-WebSocket-Version in the request header.

Comment: In the [feature request for websocket support in Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2007) there’s a [workaround for non-blocking interaction with websockets from Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2007#issuecomment-628166243).

Comment: Hi Gallaicio. Yes, I noticed this part. :) However, I am quite struggling to recover the data from passing through the websocket.

Answer (score 0):

After you read my comment and get informed about scraping, and decide to proceed carefully,

Python can retrieve this JSON with just a few lines of code

```
import requests
url = "https://api.londonstockexchange.com/api/gw/lse/instruments/alldata/CS1"
response = requests.get(url=url).json()
# print some data from the json
print(response_json)
print(response_json.get("description"))
print(response_json.get("bid"))
```

I found this data using the "network" tab, a few more show up when you hit "reload", but they seem to be empty.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your replay.

I notices those data, Unfortunately, this is nor complete and I am looking for the full time series from the chart. CF. EDIT 1

Comment: Oh yeah I re-read your question and see you specifically asked for the chart data. I'm sorry my answer was kinda unrelated.
I'm unable to make sense of that data as well, sadly.